# RegEx to move punctuation outside of tag?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

For data-cleaning purposes, I need to move punctuation (commas and periods) that occur right before certain closing tags (`a`, `b`,`i`, `strong`, `em`) to the other side of those closing tags.

For example, this bit of text:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet,</i> consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Should be transformed into this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet</i>, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

If possible, it would be neat if the RegEx could also move spaces which occur at the end of tags, though I imagine this could be accomplished by simply running the `preg_replace` twice, once for spaces, and again for punctuation. For instance:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet, </i>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet</i>, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: Asking us to write it for you is not how to use this site. Good luck, and god-speed! I recommend you start by writing a regex that puts the characters you want to move in a capture group, and then moves them to the other side in the replacement string.

Comment: should it consider such case `<i> amet,go, </i>` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Good point. I think not – this question is primarily concerned with cleaning punctuation near the closing tag, so figuring out whether punctuation inside the tag should be followed by a space, or figuring out whether a space after the opening tag should be moved to the other side of that opening tag, seems to fall outside the current scope.

Comment: Should the question title be edited to clarify this point? I tried to come up with a more accurate title, but everything I tried seemed too verbose. If someone has a better idea, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @4castle: FWIW, I'm planning to answer this question myself :)

Comment: @IllyaMoskvin Please mark one of the answers below as the accepted answer, so this question is deemed resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method uses two capture groups: one captures the comma or period followed by zero or more spaces, the second captures the closing tag. `preg_replace` is used to reverse their order.

```
$string = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet, </i>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>';
$pattern = '/([,.] *)(<\/(?:a|b|em|i|strong)>)/g';
$replacement = '$2$1';

$result = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );
```

Here is an [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ8sX8/2).

Comment: Fixed. Feel free to edit the answer if it is unsatisfactory. Thanks for the tip re: `\0`, that's neat!

Comment: Looking good now :) It's always better to use a non-capturing group when possible because it executes faster, and doesn't mess with the capture groups in the match.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all the issues about [the horrors awaiting the regex parsing of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1270789), this works for me:

```
$re = "/([\\W]+)(<\\/(a|b|em|i|strong)>)/"; 
$str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet, </i>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>"; 
$subst = "$2$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

You can check it out [online here](https://regex101.com/r/hR2wY6/1).

Comment: No need to double escape everything: `([\W]+)(\<\/\b(a|b|em|i|strong)\b\>`. Additionally, if you use another delimiter (e.g. `~`), your regex becomes even clearer: [**`~(\W+)(</\b(a|b|em|i|strong)\b>)~`**](https://regex101.com/r/hR2wY6/2)

Comment: The `\b` isn't needed, because you have character literals on both sides of those words which aren't words.

Comment: The double escapes are coming from regex101's code generator. I've got rid of the `\b`s and a couple of other unnecessary escape characters however.

Comment: If you use single quotes for a regex in PHP, it will never have the issue of mistakenly using string escape sequences. Yeah, I'm not sure why the code generator does that :/

Comment: FWIK it double escapes backslashes within double-quoted string to ensure a `\3` or such octal escape sequences are not interpreted as such `\003` that denotes `End of Text` character instead of a back-reference to third capturing group. @4castle